# Text below table

Tags: html, css, text, css-tables

The text won't go inside the table. Is it a problem with the divs?  I didn't find an answer for this problem.

Here's the CSS and HTML code:

```css
.subtype {
  border: 2px solid #c6c6c6;
  background-color: white;
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: top;
}

ol {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="submit">What would you like to submit?</br>
    </br>
    <ul>
      <li>Submission Type *</li>
    </ul>
    </br>
    <div class="subtype">
      <ol>
        <div class="arrows">
          <i class="icon-arrow-combo"></i>
        </div>
        <li><a href="#">Brand and Marketing</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sample Submit2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sample Submit3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sample Submit4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ol>

    </div>
    <ul>
      </br>
      <li>Choose one of the following options *</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: sumbit form]

Comment: Add `margin:0` to `ol`.

Comment: You appear to have a few issues with your markup, fix those problems and you will likely find that it will display correctly. In particular a `div` cannot be a child to an `ol` or `ul`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try this:*

```
.subtype {
    min-height: 30px; /*/height change to min-height/*/
    //more code...
}

ol {
    height: 20px; /*/remove this/*/
    //more code...
}
```

```css
.subtype {
  border: 2px solid #c6c6c6;
  background-color: white;
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 30px;
  text-align: top;
}

ol {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div class="subtype">
  <ol>
    <div class="arrows">
      <i class="icon-arrow-combo"></i>
    </div>
    <li><a href="#">Brand and Marketing</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sample Submit2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sample Submit3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sample Submit4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `height: 30px` on these elements and maybe set `height: auto` if you want the text to fit the table.

```css
.subtype {
  border: 2px solid #c6c6c6;
  background-color: white;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: top;
}

ol {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div class="subtype">
  <ol>
    <div class="arrows">
      <i class="icon-arrow-combo"></i>
    </div>
    <li><a href="#">Brand and Marketing</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sample Submit2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sample Submit3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sample Submit4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```